# How to launch short codes on mobile device?

Tags: c++, mobile, symbian, s60

Nokia has a long list of short codes on Symbian that can be applied to on-device data, such as

*#0000# - to check the phones software revision type,

*#7780# - to restore factory settings,

etc (the list is long)

If given a short code, how can I launch it? The program should not be aware of the functionality of the short code, it should just execute it. I am particularly interested in device short codes (not operator USSD codes). How does the native dialer do that?

Can you please provide a code example in C++ for S60 3rd or 5th edition?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a generic way to do this.

From a pure Platform Security perspective, I expect only the phone manufacturer or operator to be able to give your application the capability to restore the handset factory settings.

As for the other short codes, your best bet is to find a single Symbian OS C++ API that matches one single code.

For example, firmware version can be obtained via `SysUtil::GetSWVersion`

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer, though it does not solve my problem (and I am still a firm believer there is some library support for this known to Nokia/OEMs only). If anyone is aware of a solution, please post it here.